# "Frequent Searches leading to this page " SEO significance

Tags: seo, keywords, anchor

On a lot of websites, I find a section with heading "Frequent Searches leading to this page ". 
Such section contains the main keywords of the page repeated in multiple combinations.

Is this used to assert the anchor texts or keywords of the page to search engine crawlers ? 
Or is it only to help human viewers of the page to find that page again through a search engine next time ?

Generally such a section is present at either the bottom of the page or at the side of the page.

Example : Open below link on Desktop browser 
https://www.zomato.com/pune/barbeque-nation-jm-road#

Go to the bottom of the page ( Ctrl+f for "FREQUENT SEARCHES LEADING TO THIS PAGE" ). 
That section contains below words with all of them being hyperlinks pointing to the above page itself.

> barbeque nation, bbq nation pune, barbeque nation pune rates, barbeque
>   nation deccan pune, barbeque nation menu

Comment: It's a little unclear what you question is and you might need to edit it, so its received better by the community. If I'm correct you mean keywords in a sidebar or a part outside the main content that uses keywords and links to other pages? if so, then Google rewards little to none content outside of the main content area. Google estiblishes is what is menu/footer/ad content on every page. Internal anchor texts tell Google what the page is about but by no means is it the sole factor.. you could use Menu item 1 and still rank. Also, repeated keywords are capped, and density is late 1990.

Comment: @SimonHayter I think I get it.

Comment: The referenced section is not for humans... it is at the absolute bottom of the page and not where a user could benefit from it. It is an old SEO trick that will not actually do much of anything or more likely anything at all for the sites search performance. If you are thinking of doing something like this, it is barely worth the effort.

Comment: Ah I see now, stupid website. Stuck in 90's.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks. I have updated the question by expanding the example. Such words ( keywords ) are present either at the right side or at the bottom of web page generally.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks for the insight. Yes, I was thinking of doing the same. In Google Webmasters, I could see the top `Content Keywords` ( except the first two ) are not actually denoting my website. The runner ups in that list includes currency ( "INR" ), "persons", "half" and other words which have high frequency.

Comment: Google cares about user experience and has many different ways of establishing the quality of the page, primary proximity of links and the length of the links, the same way Google is able to tell if your links on your website are too close to another when on a mobile device (you get a warning in WMT), I'd imagine with long links like that and how close together they are it will not serve them well. If you want to get credit for related pages then use tags... but keep it to max 5 as that's the golden number, and what Stack Exchange users. Or use a breadcrumb system.

Comment: But no need to use intent + type + area + i.e "buy Chinese in Bournemouth" use tags like this Chinese, Bournemouth and if it has a rating for example 5 stars then you could do Chinese, Bournemouth, 5 Star... that way people find it useful, they may want just Chinese in Bournemouth so clicking that will list those, they may want other options in Bournemouth like Curry, and if they want the best of the best clicking 5 star etc.. only examples but things that work are things users use.. not things that silly administrators think work :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Drop Classic Old Keyword Research technique as that is no-more beneficial, so better adapt new one. Sync keywords, synonyms and relate them so Google will pick best one out from your web-content when some one searches for same.
2. Create web-pages accordingly and indent should be not only having unique as everybody is writing unique contents these days but use synonyms, or user generated terms in web-content (for this proper keyword analysis is done)
   Reference: [https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/google-synonyms/](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.bg/2015/09/matt-cutts-gadgets-google-and-seo_8.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is an attempt to get synonyms used in the text of the page.

I had a boss that was always asking "Why aren't we ranking for 'Blue Widget Salem Oregon'"  When the page title was "Widget Azure Salem OR".  The user clearly was searching for the widget we had, but was phrasing the search slightly differently than the official name of the product.

That site now has such a feature in attempt to use various phrasing of search terms.